# React Native State Update

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Basically I render the form again when isLoading changes from false true to show latest change.
When I simply render a Textview of {EntryFee}, it updates the text fine but
the state value of the input in CreateTextInput is not updating. I set up the state as such:

```
   const [EntryFee, onChangeEntryFee] = useState("");
```

I retrieve value and set `EntryFee`:

```
useEffect(() => {
        var data = getData();
        data.then((d)=>{;
        onChangeEntryFee(d['entry_fee']);
        setIsLoading(true);


     })
  }, []);
```

I pass in the variable EntryFee:

```
        <CreateTextInput
        style={styles.Label}
        input={EntryFee}
        editable={editable}
        nameOfInput={"Entry Fee Per Hour"}
        MaterialIcons={"person"} toolTipText={"The charging fee that occurs during the first hour entry of carpark"}
        inputFunction={onChangeEntryFee}
        confirmInputFunction={EFValidate}
        />
```

CreateTextInput:

```
export function CreateTextInput({ value,nameOfInput, icontype, toolTipText, inputFunction, confirmInputFunction }) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(value);
  const [inputColor, setInputColor] = useState("rgba(0,0,0,1)");

  const [toolTipVisible, setToolTipVisible] = useState(false);
  const [toolTipDesc, setToolTipDesc] = useState(toolTipText);
  const [nameToolTipColor, setToolTipColor] = useState(false);

  function validateInput() {
    if ((input == null) || (input == "")) {
      confirmInputFunction(false);
      setInputColor("rgba(255,0,0,1)")
    } else {
      inputFunction(input)
      confirmInputFunction(true);
      setInputColor("rgba(0,255,0,1)")
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', width: '100%', paddingLeft: '10%', marginTop: '10%' }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', height: 33, marginBottom: -9 }}>
        <MaterialIcons name={icontype} size={18} color="black" />
        <Text> {nameOfInput}</Text>
        <View style={{ marginLeft: '2%' }}>
          <Tooltip
            arrowSize={{ width: 15, height: 8 }}
            backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0, 0.5)"
            isVisible={toolTipVisible}
            content={<Text>{toolTipDesc}</Text>}
            placement="top"
            topAdjustment={-25.5}
            onClose={() => setToolTipVisible(false)}
          >
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setToolTipVisible(true)}>
                <MaterialIcons name="info-outline" size={18} color={toolTipVisible ? 'white' : 'red'} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </Tooltip>
        </View>
      </View>
      <TextInput
        style={[styles.inputPassword, { borderBottomColor: inputColor }]}
        onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
        onChangeText={setInput}
        onBlur={validateInput}
        value={input} />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    width: '90%',
    marginBottom: '10%',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
  },
  inputPassword: {
    height: 40,
    width: '90%',
    marginBottom: '10%',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
  },
});
```

Comment: `CreateTextInput` doesn't consume an `input` prop, but it does have an `input` state. What are you trying to accomplish by passing a prop `input={EntryFee}`?

Comment: match Props name with CreateTextInput

Comment: @DrewReese I am passing it via value, and then as you can see I use the setInput(value)

Comment: @SurenderKumar I did it as above, does that not work? I still need the CreateTextInput to have its own usestate, if I use the variable input as parameter, then I can't have the same in usestate,,,

Comment: Passing what via value? You don't pass any `value` prop to `CreateTextInput` so the `value` prop you destructure is undefined. Did you mean to pass a `value` prop instead of `input`, i.e. `value={EntryFee}`, instead of `input={EntryFee}`, so you've a defined initial `input` state in `CreateTextInput`? It's still not clear what the issue is and/or what it is that you want to accomplish. Can you clarify both for us as we can help you?